# disable cloning in angularJS drag and drop

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, clone

i created an shopping cart using using angularJS drag and drop. when i drag the item from catalog to cart and drop it, it goes successfully in the cart,
the problem is when i drag and drop same item in the cart, it again accept the product and add it in the cart.

how to remove this cloning?

to access the complete code please download it from here [click to download the .rar file](http://demo.webinitiator.biz/angularjsdemo/drag.rar)

or here is the code of main index file 
the bold code below is attachment of CSS and script you can download the same version from the .rar file above or by googling the script name.

`

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Drag &amp; Drop</title>

**<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>**

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js">
```

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.7/angular.min.js">
```

```
**<script src="angular_drag_drop/angular-dragdrop.js"></script>

<link href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">**

<style>

    .thumbnail { height: 280px !important; }

    .btn-droppable { width: 180px; height: 30px; padding-left: 4px; }

    .btn-draggable { width: 160px; }

    .emage { height: 215px; }

    h1 { padding: .2em; margin: 0; }

    #products { float:left; width: 500px; margin-right: 2em; }

    #cart { width: 200px; float: left; margin-top: 1em; }

    #cart ol { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 1em 3em; }

</style>

<script>

    $(function() {

        $("#catalog").accordion();

    });

    var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop']);

    App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

        $scope.list1 = [{'title': 'Lolcat Shirt'},{'title': 'Cheezeburger Shirt'},{'title': 'Buckit Shirt'}];


        $scope.list4 = [];

        $scope.hideMe = function() {

        $scope.list1 = [{'title': 'Lolcat Shirt'},{'title': 'Cheezeburger Shirt'},{'title': 'Buckit Shirt'}];

        return $scope.list4.length > 0;

    }

});

</script>
```

```
<body ng-controller="oneCtrl">



    <div id="products">

    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>

    <div id="catalog">

        <h2><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h2>

        <div data-drop="true" ng-model='list1' jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">

            <ul>

                <li ng-repeat='item in list1' ng-show="item.title" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}" ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, animate: true, placeholder: 'keep'}">{{item.title}} {{list1.length}} 
</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</div> 

<div id="cart">

    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Shopping Cart</h1>

    <div class="ui-widget-content">

        <ol data-drop="true" ng-model='list4' jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">

            <li ng-repeat="item in list4" ng-show="item.title" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}" ng-model="list4" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}">
{{item.title}} 
</li>

            <li class="placeholder" ng-hide="hideMe()">
Add your items here
</li>

        </ol>

    </div>

</div>


</body>

</html>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shopping cart is the only use-case for drag and drop, then you could tackle this by disabling dragging once the object is in the cart. You can do this by binding the draggable class to an expression which checks whether the object is in the cart.

```
<div ng-class="{draggable: cart.indexOf(object) != -1}"></div>
```

Here is a basic fiddle to show you what I mean - note, this doesn't include any dragging or dropping, but is just to highlight the class binding, and get you started.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/661/)

Comment: i don't have any expression to check whether the object is in cart or not.
and the fiddle you gave is not working so didn't get what u are trying to explain.
thanks

Comment: The fiddle does work, so you should get what I was trying to explain. The class "draggable" is added by the expression, which is why it appears as a blue square.

And how on earth do you not have an expression to find out if something is in your cart? How do you perform any logic on your cart objects?

Comment: didnt get what you are trying to explain. sorry :)

Comment: nope.
why don't you download the .rar file from the link above in my question and tel me where i am wrong.
i am not very much familiar to angularJS that's why am not getting you.

Comment: here is the new download link.

[Download](http://cloud9-spa.com/download/drag.rar)

Comment: Here you go - took a while!

http://www.filedropper.com/drag2

I've added a watch so every time you drop an object into list 4, it will run a check function to add an incart property to the item in the scope. I've then bound the data-drag property to this incart property, disabling it when it's in your cart.

Please don't forget to mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Also I had to change your ng-hide function, as it was evaluating a function, causing angular to reach its digest limit and spazz out. To get that functionality back, in the $watch, check if the length of list4 is greater than 0, and assign a variable to list4, like $scope.list4.hidetext = true. Then bind your ng-hide to that property, rather than a function.

Comment: i really appreciate your help cotter. but stil there is some problem.
when i drag the item and drop it in cart it disable that item and when i drag another item and drop it, the newly dragged item is disabled and allow me to drag the previous item again in the cart.
plus the cloning is activated in the products section.

Comment: Your product area shouldn't be a droppable area, and you're right, I made a mistake in my iterations. Here is the final version http://www.filedropper.com/drag3

Comment: now its working properly. thanks for the help.
but my product area have to be droppable because its drag and drop cart. so, if one can add item simply by dragging then he/she must be able to remove the item just by dragging.
or we can make another DIV for removing item.
thanks again